# How to change image on click QML

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, qml

I need to change image on click and using keyboard input (up, down, left and right). When image is selected show poster image, for unselected, show backdrop image. I managed to change it on click to poster image, but when the mouse is not in the current image it needs to go back to backdrop image.
Here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 1920
    height: 1080
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Component.onCompleted: {
        mojgrid.focus = true
    }

    function dobioResponseNapraviModel(response) {
        console.log("dobioResponseNapraviModel", typeof response)

        mojgrid.model=response
    }

    function request(){
        console.log("BOK")

        const xhr=new XMLHttpRequest()
        const method="GET";
        const url="http://api.themoviedb.org/4/list/1";
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader( "Authorization", 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI5YjBkOGVlMGQzODdiNjdhYTY0ZjAzZDllODM5MmViMyIsInN1YiI6IjU2MjlmNDBlYzNhMzY4MWI1ZTAwMTkxMyIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJhcGlfcmVhZCJdLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ.UxgW0dUhS62m41KjqEf35RWfpw4ghCbnSmSq4bsB32o');
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(xhr.readyState===XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
                var status=xhr.status;
                if(status===0 || (status>=200 && status<400)){
                    //the request has been completed successfully
//                    console.log(xhr.responseText.results)
                    dobioResponseNapraviModel(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).results)
               }else{
                    console.log("There has been an error with the request", status, JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText))
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    }





   /* function request(url, callback) {
        var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open("GET", url, true)

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState===4) {


                callback(xhr.responseText)


            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET", url)
        xhr.setRequestHeader( "Authorization", 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI5YjBkOGVlMGQzODdiNjdhYTY0ZjAzZDllODM5MmViMyIsInN1YiI6IjU2MjlmNDBlYzNhMzY4MWI1ZTAwMTkxMyIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJhcGlfcmVhZCJdLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ.UxgW0dUhS62m41KjqEf35RWfpw4ghCbnSmSq4bsB32o');
        xhr.send()

    }*/




    GridView {
        id:mojgrid
        anchors.fill: parent
        cellWidth: 250
        cellHeight: 250
        model:request()
        currentIndex: modelData.id


       /* Keys.onUpPressed: {
           request()
        }*/
      delegate: Rectangle{ id: rect; width:350;height: 400; color:'gray'
          Image{id:image; width:parent.width; height:parent.height
                 //fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                 source:"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400" + modelData.backdrop_path

                MouseArea{
                anchors.fill:parent

                onClicked: {
                    image.source="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400"+modelData.poster_path
                }
              }

          }
          Text{ text:modelData.title ;font.pointSize: 11}


      }
    }
  }
```

Somehow I need to detect if the current item or the current index is selected in GridView and based on that show different image. How can I do that? Any help would be appreciated.

p.s. Here is what I have for now:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want one image while you're pressing down with the mouse, and a different image when you let go. Then you just need to use the `pressed` property of the `MouseArea`.

```
Image {
    source: mouse.pressed ? pressedImage : unpressedImage

    MouseArea{
        id: mouse
        anchors.fill:parent
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To do the same with keyboard focus, the code is very similar:

```
Image {
    source: focus ? pressedImage : unpressedImage
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Combine both options together, like this:

```
Image {
    source: (focus || mouse.pressed) ? pressedImage : unpressedImage

    MouseArea{
        id: mouse
        anchors.fill:parent
    }
}
```

Comment: It works on click. Thanks:) Any idea how to do the same using keyboard input (left, right, up and down)? I tried binding image source with focus: ```image.source:focus?url1:url2```, but there's an error "Invalid property name image"

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: I tried this, but I can't use ```source```property two times in ```Image```. Is there another way maybe?

Comment: Well, no, you can't specify `source` twice. You can combine them though.

Answer (score 0):

In Rectangle property I added:

```
          onFocusChanged: {
              if(focus) {
              //console.log("fokus je na ", index, "mijenjam sliku")
                  img.opacity=1.0
                  img.source = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400"+modelData.poster_path
              }else{
                  img.source="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400" + modelData.backdrop_path
              }


          }
```

and

`keyNavigationEnabled: true` in `GridView`.
That solved my problem.